# Cannot get UDP port to bind to any interface, where am I going wrong?

Tags: python, sockets, interface, udp, bind

OK, so I cant seem to get a UDP port to bind to any interface, Ive tried wlan0/eth0/'0.0.0.0'/localhost etc, when using wlan0 as my interface i get no errors but when I run netstat -unl nothing is listed on the port. This should be simple, right?

```
def bind_udp_socket():
    if args.p < 1024 and os.getuid() != 0:
            print 'Cannot bind to privileged ports, run as root'
            exit(1)
    if args.v: print 'Binding to %s on UDP port %d' % (interface, args.p)
    try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    except socket.error, err:
            print 'failed to create socket:', err
            return 1
    try:
            #print type(interface) # debug
            s.bind((interface, args.p))
    except socket.error, err:
            print 'failed to bind to socket:', err
            return 1

    if args.v: print 'Socket bind complete'
    print 'Receiving data...\n'
    while True:
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(65535) # buffer size is 64 kilobytes
            if args.v: print data
    return 0
```

args.p is type int btw 
I ran the code on a different server (different OS) and same problem.

Comment: im not using windows. netstat -unl is correct for linux systems to display all listening udp ports.

Comment: What error do you get when you catch the exception and print it? Just for clarification; Are you sure you want to bind a packet socket (AF_PACKET) (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html). Most of the time the address family should be IPv4 (socket.AF_INET). As for the interface try s.bind(("",UDP_PORT)), "" binds to all local interfaces on the receiving side. Hope that helps.

Comment: ahh yes it should be AF_INET. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your address family should be IPv4 (socket.AF_INET). As for the interface,

`s.bind(("",UDP_PORT))`

binds to all local interfaces on the receiving side.